# DBCP: removeAbandoned VS eviction

Tags: java, mysql, database, connection-pooling, apache-commons-dbcp

I fail to figure out the difference between **removeAbandoned** and **eviction**. I read somewhere that removeAbandoned was deprecated, but it is not mentionned anywhere in the official doc (http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/configuration.html).

So, if someone could enlighten me, it would be greatly appreciated :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

They mean different things:

- "eviction" occurs when a database connection is unused by the application (idle in the pool) for a long enough period of time at which point it's discarded
- "abandoned connection" refers to database connection that is still in use by an application after *some* period of time, usually long enough to indicate that the connection is leaking

Eviction does not indicate a problem with your code (it's just that the application needs fewer connections after a burst of connections) but abandoned connections means that the application is holding on to a connection and is not returning to the pool.

Comment: What is the value of "some" ?